# Install4j is not able to detect the previous installations with another user by getApplicationInfoById() if installed on other than program files path

Tags: install4j

[image][image]Install4j is not able to detect the previous installations with another user by getApplicationInfoById.

I am installing app1.0.0 in C:\appdir\ with an admin account or user1.
Then I am trying to install the same app1.0.0 in C:\Program files\appdir with an administrator account or user2. So before that, I am checking if the same application is already installed? using the app id.
the expected result is it should not install again in a new folder and give msg the application is already installed. but getApplicationInfoById is not able to find the previous installation.

findings:
If the application is already installed in program files then-new app is able to detect by getApplicationInfoById in different users as well.

If the application is already installed other than program files then-new app is able to detect by getApplicationInfoByDir in different users as well.

If the application is already installed other than program files then-new app is not able to detect by getApplicationInfoById in different users as well.

Note: App id is the same for previous and new apps.
Note: Install4j 8.0.8 version used

```
// Check if the user has already installed the application
```

ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo applicationInfo =
ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoByDir(context.getInstallationDirectory());

```
if (applicationInfo == null) {
    Util.logInfo(null, "prev installation not found in current installtion dir");
    Util.logInfo(null, context.getApplicationId().toString());

    // if installation not found same path then check everywhere using app Id
    ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo[] applicationInfos =
        ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById(context.getApplicationId());


    
    for (int i = 0; i < applicationInfos.length; i++) {
        Util.logInfo(null, "prev installation detected with diff path ");
        if (i == 1){
            Util.logInfo(null, "multiple installtion detected");      
        }

        context.setInstallationDirectory(applicationInfos[i].getInstallationDirectory());
        applicationInfo = applicationInfos[i];
        
    }

// The application has never been installed before
if (applicationInfo == null){
        return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not important if the installation directory is inside the program files directory or not. What makes the difference is if the "Request privileges" action has been executed. Only then can the installer save the previous installation directory in a public part of the registry. Otherwise, a user-specific part of the registry must be used that is not readable by other users.

Comment: So I already added the "Request privileges" action in the project we check the image which I have attached. Also facing the same issue in both cases of  "fall back to user-specific installation directory"  is true & false cases. Please if required any changes in the "Request privileges"action.

Comment: Please suggest required changes in the "Request privileges"action @Ingo

Comment: If the "fall back to user-specific installation directory" property is deselected, no installation will take place without elevated rights and this issue should not occur, except of the previous installation directory is not writable by the other user.

Comment: Yes, @ingo I have tested it is working as per your comment. Is there any way non-admin users also write the previous installation directory in a public part of the registry so installation will be detected by the admin and other users?

Comment: Unfortunately not. For non-admin users there is no common writable part of the registry.

Comment: What is the behavior on mac not able to detect the previous installation by application Id using same user as well @Igno Kegel

Comment: Could be the same reason